# como colocar texto num while em php apenas uma vez

Tags: php, html, fancybox, galeria

Eu tenho uma galeria de imagens feita com *fancybox* que todas as imagens que aparecem vêem da base de dados.
a galeria é algo [assim](http://fancybox.net/).

Eu tenho isto:

```html
<div id="exterior">
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gibellino");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from exterior");
 
 $first = 'first';
 echo "<h4>Exterior</h4>";
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $img = $row['img'];
  echo "
   <a href='images/angel/$img' rel='exterior' title='$img'><img src='images/angel/$img' alt='' id='$first'><span></span></a>
  ";
  
  $first = '';
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 
?>

</div>
```

e mais 4 divs iguais só muda os id's praticamente. E fica algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E queria que no `border-bottom` fosse possível adicionar texto mas não consigo pois se puser dentro do *while* aparecem todas as imagens e se puser fora do *while* ficar debaixo da imagem. Que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Isso talvez seja mais uma questão de CSS do que do PHP em si.

```css
.pai{
  background:purple;
 }

.pai > .filho {
  background:pink;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.text{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

.pai > .filho:nth-child(odd) .text{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}

.pai > .filho:nth-child(even) .text{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  
  <div class="filho">
    <div class="text">Texto</div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="filho">
    <div class="text">Texto</div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="filho">
    <div class="text">Texto</div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="filho">
    <div class="text">Texto</div>
  </div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Para que serve o > no css? Como .pai > .filho